# Matlab Histogram of randomly spread data

Tags: matlab, histogram, curve

I am a newbie to matlab and I already search a whole bunch of different sites but I didn't quite find a solution (at least an understandable one).

I have a matrix 290x233 with double values ranging from 0.1 to 4.7. I want to generate a histogram out of all the data in this matrix in way that there are bars for a range of 0.5 -> I want to be able to see how many values there are within 0 to 0.5, from 0.5 to 1 and so on ...

So far I managed to get kind of close plotting the bars. Using this code:

```
bins=[0.25:0.5:4.75];
n2=histc(a_dif_1, bins);
bar(bins,n2,'hist');
```

I managed to get a result where there are a whole bunch of peaks within each bin (see image below). This means it shows me the occurance of each single value within the bin range.

[image]

then I found out about the "stacked" option and using

```
bins=[0.25:0.5:4.75];
n2=histc(a_dif_1, bins);
bar(bins,n2,0.8,'stacked','b');
```

This way I at least got big bars just showing the TOTAL number of occurances within 1 bin (therefor 10 rectangleshaped bars shown below).

[image]

Right now I am wondering if this is the right way to draw bars just showing the total amount of values within a bin?? Apart of this I noticed that my bars I kind of getting set off the center of the bin (the bars to the right side are not axactly in the middle of two x-ticks) - did I mess something up with the bins??

As kind of a bonus I finally would like to draw a curve on top of the bars. The curve should show follow the peaks I described before in a very generalized way so I can give a more detailed information about the distribution of the data apart of the bars.

Thanks for every kind of help or ideas!

#### UPDATE

THANK YOU VERY MUCH for the hints. I changed the `histc` to `hist`

```
bins=[0.25:0.5:4.75]; 
hist(a_dif_1(:), bins)
```

...and Matlab is giving me exactly what I wanted:

[image]

Comment: You can just upload the images, and someone with the rights can edit your post to include those images.

Comment: have you tried just `hist(a_dif_1(:), bins)` (assuming `a_dif_1` is your matrix)? If yes, what is wrong with the output?

Comment: I think you've mistaken how bins work in `hist` versus `histc`. In `hist`, you want `bins` to store the center of each bin. In `histc`, you want `bins` to store the edges of each bin. In your code, `bins` appears to be storing the center, not edges, ie as @AndreasWallner suggests, you want `hist`, not `histc`.

Comment: Thanks giving me a solution for the bar issue. 
The only thing missing for me now is the overlay of the CURVE. To be more precisely I would like to reproduce the peak structure in PICTURE I (like fitting a line to the top of the bars), to show the real distribution of the values besides the very abstract information given by the bars. Any thoughts???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = 0.1;
b = 4.7;
r = a + (b-a).*rand(290,233);
bins=[0.25:0.5:4.75];
hist(r(:))
hist(r(:),bins)
```

is that ok for you?

[image]

Comment: Yes absolutely, thx!! Only the curve-question stays unanswered so far.